# How to identify a missing plug-in?

Tags: vst, cubase, vsti

I had my MacBook Pro's motherboard replaced by Apple, and when i got the machine back everything was seemingly normal, yet there were strange things, such as that iCloud no longer knew my password. I assume they for some reason restored via Timemachine and must have messed up permissions (i tried a repair).

Problem is, ever since the replacement was done, a very large and long-worked-on Cubase project of mine is missing a plugin. The track name gives no reference to it and i can – for the heck of it – not remember what plugin was loaded in that slot.

I tried finding out what plugin it was, but to no avail. There is no information anywhere, and the Plugin Manager doesn't bring up any clues either.

The only thing i was able to do was open the project file in a text editor and look for the track name. Via that method i found the plugin UID but that doesn't really help either, because i would have to know which plugin the UID belongs to – and i don't.

Can anyone help me with this? Any trick to find out the plugin name? Or anyone good enough with taking apart those project files, maybe knowing where to find a clue on what plugin it was that got missing?

Thank you!

Comment: No-one's picked up on this yet... so I'm tempted to say the only people who may be able to figure a plugin from a UUID are Steinberg. That is, of course, if the UUIDs are a) registered with them & b) not simply unique to each computer.

Comment: So just to clarify, are any plugins actually _missing_ from your database? Because I'm just thinking there could be a way to find which are missing from iOS's registry or something.

Comment: just another vaguely relevant comment - even if I've moved a project from one machine to another, even PC to Mac, missing plugins tend to be specifically noted by name [not that I've ever paid absolute & full attention, I generally know there will be some things missing & I'll have to replace them with local resources]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to identify the plugin by opening the CPR file in a text editor, looking for the track name and investigating the detailed info adjacent to it. I found something called "OriginalPluginName" and there i found the name of the missing plugin.